# Email not being sent Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

In controller(maildata and query_string are arrays and being sent):

```
$this->dispatch(new SendBulkRegisterEmail($maildata,$query_string));
```

In SendBulkRegisterEmail

```
public $query_string, $maildata;

    public function __construct($maildata, $query_string)
    {
        $this->query_string = $query_string;
        $this->maildata = $maildata;
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        try{
            for ($i=0; $i < count($this->maildata) ; $i++) {
                $mailers = $maildata[$i];
                Mail::send('mails.new_user_mail', $mailers, function($message)  use ($mailers)
                {
                    $message->to($mailers["toemail"],$mailers['studentname'])->subject($mailers['subject']);
                });
            }
        }catch(Exception $e){
        }
    }
```

The mail is not being sent. Someone please help
Thanks in Advance

Comment: did you configure data from mail??

Comment: any error in catch block??

Comment: No errors are being thrown. Email is being sent from other functions

Comment: check for ` $mailers` try to print and check is it null or not!

Comment: did you send to log?